# PowerBuilder change menu on runtime

Tags: menu, menuitem, mdi, powerbuilder

Can you change a MDI window's menu at runtime?

I tried `Changemenu()` function but I failed in registering the menu itself. 
When I debug, `menu` shows it's null.

```
menu m_menu
m_menu = m_base_menu
// where m_base_menu is the menu object
this.changemenu(m_menu)
```

`m_menu` is NULL on the line..

I also tried instantiating it

```
m_menu = create menu
```

still to no avail. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem. I need to change the menu depending on the user group.

I tried this:

```
ChangeMenu(m_menu) -> m_menu is null
```

tried to instantiate the menu but still null

In PB11, this is working, then we migrated to PB12.5. 
For sometime it was working on PB12.5, but when we removed the titlebar and controlmenu of the pfc window w_master, changemenu is already null, thus we cannot change the menu on runtime anymore

How to resolve this?

Comment: Finally made it work. As I was typing the above, I thought of trying to enable the titlebar and controlmenu again and see if it works. So I did enable the titlebar and controlmenu and the ChangeMenu worked!

Does this mean that Changemenu will only work if the titlebar or the controlmenu of the window are enabled?
I have been using PB since 2006 from PB 9, 10, 11.5, 12.5 and haven't encountered this before. Or maybe my previous company didn't use ChangeMenu on their applications :-)

Comment: Wow! haha. I have not solved this and resorted to another way. But thanks anyway. I cannot accept answer though because I have not tried it out yet. Maybe when I get back to PB Programming. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the sample in the docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37787_1100/html/objcont_merged/CJAEJAAD.htm), I'd try

```
ChangeMenu (m_base_menu)
```

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: yeah i havent tested that because i cant pass the menu properly. even though i have an object m_base_menu, when I debug it it shows null

Comment: When you're looking in the debugger, I expect you're looking at the implicit global variable, which isn't there because there isn't an instance of the menu instantiated yet.

Comment: no, i tried instatiating it with the use of m_menu.. still having nulls tho

Comment: Sorry, which is null, and do you see the menu change?

Comment: What's the return code from ChangeMenu? What kind of MDI window are you trying to change: sheet or frame? And where is the script? Have you tried changing it on a main window? And you still haven't told me which is null and now I'm wondering if you tested that nullness in script.